# Can I use Azure file share with VM Classic?

Tags: ubuntu, azure, filesystems, mount, file-transfer

I have a VM classic and I want to create a new VM to replace it. So I want to make use of the file share feature of Azure to transfer my files on the old VM.  Both VM are running on Ubuntu.

However, though I can successfully connect the fileshare with the new VM, the old VM gives Mount Error 13.

The VM classic is Ubuntu 14.04, while the new one is Ubuntu 18.04

Is it just not possible to transfer files this way? What are the other options?

Comment: Did my answer solve your problem? If so please upvote and/or accept my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The fact that your VM is a classic one has no bearing on whether you can mount Azure file shares. The process of mounting the share occurs solely in the VM OS which has no idea whether it is a classic or ARM VM.

The issue is probably down to the version of Ubuntu. 14.04 is the earliest supported OS for mounting Azure Files, but only using SMB 2.1, from VMs in the same region as the file share. If you are trying to use SMB 3, or trying to mount on VM in a different region to where the file share lives, then you need a minimum of 16.04.

Answer (score 0):

As Sam Cogan has already stated, this has nothing to do whether it is a classic or ARM VM.

This usually can happen due to an unencrypted communication channel or if there are firewall rules set on the virtual network or storage account. Have a look here for further information and possible solutions: ["Mount error(13): Permission denied" when you mount an Azure file share](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-troubleshoot-linux-file-connection-problems#mount-error13-permission-denied-when-you-mount-an-azure-file-share)

This also might be of interest to you [Use Azure Files with Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux). There you will find:

> The recommended way to mount an Azure file share on Linux is using SMB 3.0. By default, Azure Files requires encryption in transit, which is only supported by SMB 3.0. Azure Files also supports SMB 2.1, which does not support encryption in transit, but you may not mount Azure file shares with SMB 2.1 from another Azure region or on-premises for security reasons. Unless your application specifically requires SMB 2.1, there is little reason to use it since most popular, recently released Linux distributions support SMB 3.0:

[image]